# Is there any Way to change the redirection button url of Keycloak from default to another url?

Tags: url, redirect, keycloak, logout

Hello I got the follow issue:  after logout from keycloak :
[image]

It redirects me to a default confirmation page from keycloak:
[image]

So is there any way after Logout to redirect the user to a different url? And not to the default confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter in your logout request to your preferred value.

Note that it may be necessary to set `Valid post logout redirect URIs` in the client inside the admin console.